# PhoneGap App Orientation using xcode and cordova

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I want to do application in PhoneGap using cordova in xCode but supported only landscape orientation but I have just created new project using cordova in xcode and view is appear only in portrait on simulator, So What should I do to make it landscape?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that change from -info.plist file.

Supported interface orientations (iPad) and Supported interface orientations for iphone these two tags are available. you can add other tags in it.

Or click on project name in Package explorer go to Target -> summary. there you can find Supported interface orientation click whatever you want to.

now in simulator you can check it via command + arrow keys.

Comment: Hey Bhavesh, Thanks for your reply, But I already done that and its helpless.

Comment: No, before posting this question I tried it, what you said, But it does not work.

Comment: Okay then how did you solve it. share it so that someone might get help from it.